# Will denying all ip address except my own create a problem?

Tags: server

I want to deny access to my website from any source except for myself and the server. What I did is edit .htaccess

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from MYIP, MY_SERVER_IP
```

Will this create any problem? Will some plugin trying to access my website and get denied?

Comment: Might I ask why you'd want to do that? If it is necessary, why not just local host your site?  

Comment: I am used to put developing site on the actual server. For my previous projects I will use a temporary URL, but for this project I am using the actual URL so I don't want others to see the underdeveloped website. Besides, you might think otherwise but moving wp website or changing its URL is a hassle to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question and for any others that might come along to this thread;

**Will it be a problem?**
Denying access from the `.htaccess` file will block all connections unless permitted, so if you are using plugins that need to execute API calls or similar, you'll need to whitelist those IPs.

So in totality, not really. Ultimately it depends on your site's structure and the outbound/inbound connections it needs.

**For completeness:**
The following code prevents anyone from viewing your website depending on the version of apache you have running. Visitors will see a `403 Forbidden` status while visiting your website.

**Apache 2.2**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

**Apache 2.4**

```
Require all denied
```

It's important to note, however, that using the above will inadvertently block you from accessing the directory also. To solve this you'll likely want to use the following;

**Apache 2.2**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

#Allow specific IP's...
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

**Apache 2.4**

```
Require local
```

**Syntax**
The syntax is sensitive so, `order deny, allow` should be `order deny,allow` (no space after `,`) otherwise some Apache versions will show Server Error because `order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow' (Says Apache Log)`

You can find your IP by using typing [`what is my ip`](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB1008GB1008&oq=what%20is%20my%20ip&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l7.2355j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) into google.
Whereas `127.0.0.1` is a special-purpose IPv4 address and is called the localhost or loopback address. All computers use this address as their own, but it doesn't let computers communicate with other devices as a real IP address does.

There's plenty of info using these commands on the web, the bulk of the info posted here can be found in the following [Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507645/htaccess-deny-from-all).